# Translate a bunch of booleans to a list of enums using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have a class like this:

```
class From
{
    public bool FlagOne { get; set; }
    public bool FlagTwo { get; set; }
    public bool FlagThree { get; set; }
}
```

... and I want to convert a list of these into a list of these:

```
class To
{
    public List<Flag> Flags { get; set; }
}
```

... where `Flag` looks like this:

```
public enum Flag
{
    One,Two,Three
}
```

I write some code:

```
var froms = new List<From>
{
    new From {
        FlagOne = false,
        FlagTwo = true,
        FlagThree = true
    },
    new From {
        FlagOne = true,
        FlagTwo = false,
        FlagThree = true
    }
};

var tos = froms.Select(from => new To {
    Flags = // ....... what?  what goes here?
}).ToList();
```

The *names* of the enum values and the boolean flags to not matter.  There should be no reflection necessary.

### Context

I have a database table like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
| FlagOne | FlagTwo | FlagThree | 
+=========+=========+===========|
|    0    |    1    |     1     |
+---------+---------+-----------+
|    1    |    0    |     1     |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

and I want to make a UI that looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Lorem blahdiblah FlagTwo, FlagThree |
+-------------------------------------+
| Lorem blahdiblah FlagOne, FlagThree |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I don't *have* to do this; I just thought it was an interesting problem to solve with LINQ, and couldn't find any answers.

Comment: There are answers below that will do what you asked of them, however they may not actually be getting at what you really need/should do. what is causing you want to do this.  Do you have control over either the class or the enum you are trying to do this from?  Can you change the structure?  Do you in particular want a list of flags or just a way to check which flags are set?

Comment: I don't see any reason to convert this. One can use Enums with a Flag attribute. This enables the programmer to represent a serie of attributes (bits) compactly and test each of these bits separately.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I add some context to the question.  I think that the data is being represented as it should be at the database end, and the enums are essentially properties on the view model.  I went for a list of enums as rather than a bitmask because they will eventually end up in a Knockout.js view model, and I already have logic for handling these nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to deal with this is using nullable `Flag`s in a collection, and then filter out the `null`s, like this:

```
var tos = froms
    .Select(f => new To {
        Flags = new[] {
            f.FlagOne   ? (Flag?)Flag.One : null,
            f.FlagTwo   ? (Flag?)Flag.Two : null,
            f.FlagThree ? (Flag?)Flag.Three : null
        }
        .Where(f => f.HasValue)
        .Select(f => f.Value)
        .ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

The array created in the assignment of `Flags` has three items of type `Flag?` - one for each flag. The flags that correspond to an unset property become `null`s; the flags corresponding to set properties become the nullable `Flag.XYZ`.

The rest is simple: the `Where()` filters out the `null`s, the `Select()` drops nullability, and finally `ToList()` makes the results a list.

Comment: Thanks.  Learned something from this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert it?

You can implement flags in Enums as well:

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo : int {
   Bit1 = 0x01,
   Bit2 = 0x02,
   Bit3 = 0x04
}
```

You can then check if a flag is active simply by a bitwise AND operation. For instance:

```
Foo aVariable = Foo.Bit1|Foo.Bit3;//both bit1 and bit3 are enabled
```

Check if bit3 is enabled:

```
if((aVariable&Foo.Bit3) != 0x00) {
   //flag is enabled, now do something
}
else {
   //flag is disabled, do something else
}
```

The advantage of using such constructions is that the bits are represented more compact, operations (like a bitwise OR) can be handled more faster and you don't have to worry about semantics of the bits (the enum hides the actual value of the bits).

If you really want to enumerate over the possible values, you can use a generic construction:

```
public static class Bar {

  public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateAtoms<T> (this T input) where T : enum {
    foreach(T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
      if((input&val) != 0x00) {
        yield return value;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I think that in my case (data is coming from a database) the three separate boolean values are more correct, as it gives context within the database layer more easily (from three columns) rather than a binary string in one column, with meaning only applied by the data access layer after reading.  Thanks for your time - I learned a lot from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
To ConvertFromFromToTo(From from)
{
    List<Flag> flags = new List<Flag>();

    if (from.FlagOne)   flags.Add(Flag.One);
    if (from.FlagTwo)   flags.Add(Flag.Two);
    if (from.FlagThree) flags.Add(Flag.Three);

    return new To { Flags = flags };
}
```

```
var tos = froms.Select(ConvertFromFromToTo).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a good clear solution, but unfortunately does not use LINQ!  Cheers.

Comment: That's because LINQ doesn't provide any advantage here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear exactly how you intend for the flag bools to map into enum values, but you would probably want to use something like this:

```
Flags = new List<Flag> { 
from.FlagOne ? Flag.One : Flag.Two,
from.FlagTwo ? Flag.One : Flag.Two,
from.FlagThree ? Flag.One : Flag.Two }
```

The main question being what you want Flag.One, Flag.Two, and Flag.Three to represent.

Comment: Cheers for the response.  I went with a more complete solution from dasblinkenlight.